# Excel VBA to merge rows of the ranges into 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

Good day, i am new to Excel VBA and i need a function to unite two ranges into one avoiding dublicates.

For example, i have two ranges:

one is

| ID | Student | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kate | 2 |
| 2 | Sam | 1 |

second is

| ID | Student | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Dave | 4 |
| 5 | Cole | 1 |
| 2 | Sam | 1 |

and output should be

| ID | Student | Course |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kate | 2 |
| 2 | Sam | 1 |
| 4 | Dave | 4 |
| 5 | Cole | 1 |

If the rows are dublicates is determined on ID values which are unique. I would really appreciate if the function would accept ranges and return array.

I tried to use `RemoveDublicates` but this function messes with original ranges and then excel exits.

Maybe somebody could've told me what is wrong here?

```vb
Function REL_UNION(Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range) As Variant

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Table As Range
    
    Dim row_c As Integer
    Dim col_c As Integer
    Dim old_r As Integer
    
    old_r = Table1.rows.Count
    row_c = Table1.rows.Count + Table2.rows.Count
    col_c = Table1.Columns.Count
    
    ReDim Arr(1 To row_c, 1 To col_c)
    Set Table = Table1.Resize(row_c)
    
    For r = old_r + 1 To row_c
        For c = 1 To col_c
            Table.Value2(r, c) = Table2.Value2(r - old_r, c)
        Next
    Next
    
    
    Table.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
   
    Arr = Table.Value2
    
    REL_UNION = Arr
        
    
End Function
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Copy one below the other. Then use the `Range.RemoveDuplicates` method.

Comment: Honestly, pretty much, but it was all unsuccessful.
Function REL_UNION(Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range) As Variant

    Dim TwoRanges As Range
    Dim Arr As Variant
    
    Set TwoRanges = UNION(Table1, Table2)
    TwoRanges.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
   
    Arr = TwoRanges.Value2
    
    REL_UNION = Arr
End Function

this is my best

Comment: Just noted that you want a function that returns an array. For a **Function** that will return an array, you cannot use the RemoveDuplicates method, because a function can only return a value, and not manipulate cells on a worksheet. In that case, @schlieman suggestion, or some variation, is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary object instead with Id+Name combined as the keys and Course Id as the items. It will remove the duplicates and then pour the unique values back to the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

### Unique Data to 2D One-Based Array

- The example procedure `getUniqueArrayTEST` utilizes the function `getUniqueArray` in the worksheet `Sheet1` of the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`). The first table starts in `A1`, the second table starts in `E1`, and the resulting table starts in `I1`. All tables have one (the same) row of headers and 3 columns. Unique is defined by the values of the first (by default) column of the two given tables.
- Adjust the values in the constants section to fit your needs.
- In the function, the lines containing `'***` designate lines that may be (redundant) not necessary in this particular case.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub getUniqueArrayTEST()

    Const s1Name As String = "Sheet1"
    Const s1First As String = "A1"
    Const s2Name As String = "Sheet1"
    Const s2First As String = "E1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "I1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create range references.
    Dim Table1 As Range
    Set Table1 = wb.Worksheets(s1Name).Range(s1First).CurrentRegion
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Set Table2 = wb.Worksheets(s2Name).Range(s2First).CurrentRegion
    
    ' Get unique data.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getUniqueArray(Table1, Table2)
    
    ' Write and clear.
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    With wb.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirst).Resize(, UBound(Data, 2))
        .Resize(rCount).Value = Data ' write to destination
        .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1) _
            .Offset(rCount).ClearContents ' clear contents below destination
    End With

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the unique values from two tables with the same number
'               of columns to a 2D one-based array. Unique is defined
'               by checking the values of the same (one) column ('UniqueColumn')
'               in each table against each other.
' Remarks:      It is assumed that the tables have one row of (same) headers
'               and at least two columns.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getUniqueArray( _
    ByVal Table1 As Range, _
    ByVal Table2 As Range, _
    Optional ByVal UniqueColumn As Long = 1) _
As Variant

    ' Validate parameters (inputs).
    
    If Table1 Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If Table2 Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = Table1.Columns.Count
    If cCount = 1 Then Exit Function
    If cCount <> Table2.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    If UniqueColumn < 1 Then Exit Function
    If UniqueColumn > cCount Then Exit Function
    
    ' Write data from ranges to Range Arrays ('rData1', 'rData2').
    
    Dim r1Count As Long: r1Count = Table1.Rows.Count
    Dim rData1 As Variant: rData1 = Table1.Value
    
    Dim r2Count As Long: r2Count = Table2.Rows.Count
    Dim rData2 As Variant: rData2 = Table2.Value
    
    ' Write unique values (Keys) and Row Data Arrays (Values)
    ' to Unique Dictionary ('dict').
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare '*** allow "A" = "a"
    
    Dim rData As Variant: ReDim rData(1 To cCount) ' Current Row Data Array
    
    Dim Key As Variant ' Current Value in Unique Column, Current Dictionary Key
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    If r1Count > 1 Then
        For r = 2 To r1Count
            Key = rData1(r, UniqueColumn)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then '*** exclude error values
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then '*** exclude blanks
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        For c = 1 To cCount
                            rData(c) = rData1(r, c)
                        Next c
                        dict(Key) = rData
                    End If
                End If '***
            End If '***
        Next r
    'Else ' No data, only headers
    End If
    
    If r2Count > 1 Then
        For r = 2 To UBound(rData2, 1)
            Key = rData2(r, UniqueColumn)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        For c = 1 To cCount
                            rData(c) = rData2(r, c)
                        Next c
                        dict(Key) = rData
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    'Else ' No data, only headers
    End If
    
    ' Write values from Row Data Arrays of Unique Dictionary to Data Array.
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To dict.Count + 1, 1 To cCount)
    
    ' Write headers.
    For c = 1 To cCount
        Data(1, c) = rData1(1, c)
    Next c
    
    Erase rData1
    Erase rData2
    
    Dim n As Long: n = 1 ' 1 for headers
    
    ' Write Row Data Arrays.
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            n = n + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(n, c) = dict(Key)(c)
            Next c
        Next Key
    End If
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    getUniqueArray = Data
    
End Function
```